# grpc status code UNAVAILABLE and details as OS error

Tags: docker, grpc, tensorflow-serving

Getting intermittent error, only when the container is brought up using docker stack deploy, working fine using docker-compose
`    grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "OS Error"
    debug_error_string = 
    "{"created":"@1565004909.399609656",
    "description":"Error received from peer",
    "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc",
    "file_line":1036,
    "grpc_message":"OS Error",
    "grpc_status":14}"

```
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
result = stub.Predict(request, 100.0)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On solution what is working is adding the retry logic,
catch the grpc error and call stub.Predict again

```
try:
        result = stub.Predict(request, 100.0)  # 100 seconds
    except grpc.RpcError as e:
        result = stub.Predict(request, 100.0)  # 100 seconds
```